# Add new Item Order Attribute Magento 2

Tags: magento2, orders, sales

I couldn't find how i could overwrite any model of order to create a new attribute like "qty" for every item_order .

Could anyone helps me?

Comment: You're going to add "qty" attributes to order entity on Magento 2? Like this Magento 1 tutorial: http://www.boolfly.com/add-custom-fields-to-order-magento-part-2/

Comment: But this is not for each order_item not?